# Can I add a 8 GB ram to my laptop ( which has 4 slots, 2 of them are occupied by 4 GB RAM)

Tags: memory, installation

My laptop is Samsung series 9 NP900X4C-A01AE which comes with 2 DDR3 RAMs each one is 4 GB

I want to add a third 8 GB RAM, would this be bad for the dual channel architecture?

Comment: Your system supports having 4 4GB modules being installed.

Comment: @Ramhound Is that correct? According to the Samsung [system specs](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/pcs/NP900X4C-A01US-specs) it has a max system memory of 8GB, not 16GB.

Comment: I would put money that it will work.  CPU supports 32 GB.  Model number you link to isn't exact.

Comment: "I want to a third 8 GB RAM"  - This won't work, highest supported density is 4GB.

Comment: I am trusting that, it actually has 4 slots, I don't feel like finding the exact model and verify in the user manual if it can be upgraded my comment is based on the fact it supports 4 modules and currently is using two 4 GB modules. Provide the manual, which is written in English, to your specific model and I will submit an answer.

Comment: I don't know why I don't find my exact PC model by searching in samsung website nor in Google! 
But this is what is get by using tools that detect Memory:
Belarc advisor tools says: 
Memory Modules c,d
7894 Megabytes Usable Installed Memory

Slot 'ChannelA-DIMM0' has 4096 MB (serial number 0000FD45)
Slot 'ChannelA-DIMM1' is Empty
Slot 'ChannelB-DIMM0' has 4096 MB (serial number 0000FB9E)
Slot 'ChannelB-DIMM1' is Empty.

And this is the result by sing " Piriform speccy " tool :
Memory slots
 Total memory slots 4
 Used memory slots 2
 Free memory slots 2

Comment: I would be skeptical about such tools. Unless they can specifically identify your machine it's basically impossible for them to tell the difference between a slot that is empty and a slot that doesn't exist at all.

Comment: So I'm wondering, how can't I find my laptop model in samsung website to check specs or read the manual ?!

Answer (score 2):

For best performance you should have the same ammount of ram on each channel. It's not absoloutely critical but it's best practice where possible.

So if you have two 4GB modules and one 8GB module in a dual channel system then you should put the two 4GB modules on the same channel.

I can't seem to find official information on your exact laptop model but the specs I found for the NP900X4C-A01US (which I assume is the same except for localisation differences) indicate that it only has two ram slots and only officially supports up to 8GB of ram total.